# Prolog: arguments not sufficiently instantiated (sum of list 1+2+...+n)

Tags: list, prolog, sum, instantiation-error

I need to write a predicate `listsum(L, S)` which is true iff L is a list of natural numbers increasing from 1 to a certain n (i.e. *[1,2,..,n]*). Now I got it working for queries of the kind `listsum(L, <any number larger than 0>)` but when I try to query for example `listsum([1,2,3], S)` it says the arguments aren't sufficiently instantiated. This is my code:

```
listsum(L,S) :- listsum(L,S,1).
listsum(L, 0, A) :- 
    N is A-1,
    N > 1,
    fromTo(1, N, L). ; true iff L is the list [1,2,...,N]
listsum(L, S, A) :-
    S > 0,
    SA is S-A,
    A1 is A+1,
    listsum(L, SA, A1).
```

If anyone could help me out on how to make this work in both ways (so also with a given value for L, querying S), it'd be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This error is a frequent problem when beginners first encounter old-fashioned Prolog code. The reason is that predicates like `(is)/2` and `(>)/2` are *not* true **relations**. Instead, they only work if their arguments are sufficiently **instantiated**.

This causes a lot of confusion, especially among beginners, and is obviously also highly unfortunate from a practical point of view. When programming in Prolog, we would like to benefit from the **generality** of relations, and not be bogged down in such low-level issues right from the start.

A declarative solution for such issues are **constraints**. Support for them differs somewhat between various Prolog systems. However, at present, the most widely used Prolog systems all ship at least with constraints over **integers**.

To use them for example in GNU Prolog, simply make the following straight-forward changes to your code:

- replace `(is)/2` with `(#=)/2`
- replace `(>)/2` with `(#>)/2`.

Thus, we obtain:

```
listsum(L,S) :- listsum(L,S,1).

listsum(L, 0, A) :-
    N #= A-1,
    N #> 1,
    fromTo(1, N, L).
listsum(L, S, A) :-
    S #> 0,
    SA #= S-A,
    A1 #= A+1,
    listsum(L, SA, A1).
```

In addition, I suggest the following definition of `fromTo/3`, if your Prolog system provides `numlist/3`:

```
fromTo(1, N, Ls) :- numlist(1, N, Ls).
```

I leave implementing `numlist/3` yourself as an easy exercise.

With these changes, we get:

```
?- listsum([1,2,3], S).
S = 6 .
```

Thus, at least we get a correct **solution**, and can now focus on remaining issues.

For example, the query does not terminate *universally*, which we can see with:

```
?- listsum([1,2,3], S), false.
nontermination
```

I leave correcting this as an exercise.

Note that some Prolog systems require you to import a library to use declarative integer arithmetic.